# Google Drive API insert new file with Untitled name

Tags: c++, qt, google-drive-api

I write my own application for GDrive on c++ and Qt; And I got problem with inserting new file to GDrive. All my uploaded files got name "Untitled". How I should create post request to send my file and valid name with extension for it?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to upload files with the Drive API, they are all described at https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads.

The file title must be provided in the `title` field of the resource representation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: Please show your request and the error message you are getting

Comment: the problem was in invalid key-value for name in json. I used "name" instead of "title"